# Setting up RBS for 2nd Site Collection

Tags: site-collection, remote-blob-storage

Few days ago I follow Microsoft's article (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663474.aspx) on Setting up RBS for SP2010.

It's all working fine for the Sales Site collection. Now, Legal department wants similar implementation for their site collection as they have over 200,000 documents. I need clarifications on step 3.

There are 5 steps:

1. Enable Filestream on the DB Server - Which is already done so I will skip.
2. Provision a BLOB store for each content database - I will do one for Legal Site Coll.
3. **Install the RBS client library on the on the first Web server - STUCK?
   Do I need to do this since I already did this for Sales Site Coll.?**
4. Enable RBS for each content database - Will do this after Step 3
5. Test RBS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bill,

Steps 1 thru 5 are applicable when you set up RBS for the first time.

For additional site collections all you have to do is follow step 2 and 4 (per Microsoft's Tech Support). I had a open ticket with them and ask them if they would clarify this for me. After exchanging 7 emails they agreed that only step 2 and 4 is necessary for additional site collection RBS setup.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: rereading it, your right to question it!

It looks like you need to run the command again with your second content database.

Frankly that's really terrible language on Microsoft's part, as I believe they are trying to explain that there is only one instance of the install even though you run the configuration command multiple times.

Comment: The RBS client library is installed only once per Web server, but RBS is configured separately for each associated content database.

Comment: I know sometimes it takes few readings and multiple heads to come to correct conclusion. I really wanted a concrete answer though.

Comment: Your absolutely right, and its never wrong to take the extra time to double check before you make a change on an environment.

Comment: Can anyone please confirm this? As I understand the article I should only be performing Step 2 and 4 (once initial setup is done) for additional site collections.